# Vote to reopen questions in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, vote-to-reopen

Currently, when I want to reopen a question via my mobile device, I have to go to Safari or other browser app to do this.

Is it possible to add an option to vote to reopen via the app itself?

Comment: No moderator tools are available in the mobile app except for voting to close

Comment: @OneFace Hence this feature request...

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this feature request. It will help the right questions to be re-opened more quickly. I mean if we allow them to be closed quickly they have the right be to be re-opened as quickly as possible. If added, more users (including me) will be able to cast re-open votes more quickly.

Answer (score -2):

Having just ran into the issue of there not being a way to reopen a closed question from the app, I have to say I found it confusing.  Not because I was seeking to reopen a closed question, but because the presence of the reopen link means that the question is closed, which was not clear to me.

Either I missed it, or it wasn't there.  Either way, the vote to reopen link seems like an obvious choice that should be there.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't really a valid answer for a feature request. It boils down to just "I agree with the request" without really adding anything, so fitting as upvote plus maybe a comment

Comment: @ShadowWizard: this is meta and a feature request at that. But this does have more than "I agree".  I am giving another reason to implemtent this feature, one that is at best tangential to the reason given by the OP.