# Impossible to revoke my vote for close

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, retracted-close-votes

After I voted for close the question it is not possible to revoke close vote from ios-app:

[image: close vote]

I can do it only from web.

I am not sure is it bug or should be a feature-request, please feel free to edit tags.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Well, you can't even [vote to reopen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245753/vote-to-reopen-in-the-ios-app) via the app. The app is limited, and tha is by design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "vote to reopen" is not same as "revoke close vote"

Comment: Of course. It's just an example that the app is missing features that might be considered basic. To have all the features, one has no choice but to use the site. (Full site, not mobile theme which is as lacking as the app)

Comment: Close voting is a subset of the /questions/{id}/flags/add API path which does not support retracting flags. This would not be possible to do in the app without changing the API.